# Edit the value of all the rows of column with the same id based on the value of another column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | Flagged |
| 1 | N | Flagged |
| 2 | N | Flagged |
| 2 | Y | Flagged |
| 2 | N | Flagged |

I have the above table. I want to check the rows in val1 with the same id, if there's at least one Y and one N then all the rows having 1 as id will be marked flagged in val2. In addition, for a more efficient code, I want the code to jump to the next id once it finds a Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `val1` columns contains only `Y` and `N` as unique values, you can group the dataframe by `id` and aggregate `val1` using `countDistinct` to count the unique values, then create a new column `flagged` corresponding the condition where distinct count > 1, finally `join` this new column with original dataframe to get the result

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

counts = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.countDistinct('val1').alias('flagged'))
df = df.join(counts.withColumn('flagged', F.col('flagged') > 1), on='id')
```

If column `val1` may contains other values along with `Y, N`, then first mask the values which are not in `Y` and `N`:

```
vals = F.when(F.col('val1').isin(['Y', 'N']), F.col('val1'))

counts = df.groupBy('id').agg(F.countDistinct(vals).alias('flagged'))
df = df.join(counts.withColumn('flagged', F.col('flagged') > 1), on='id')
```

---

```
>>> df.show()

| id|val1|flagged|
+---+----+-------+
|  1|   Y|   true|
|  1|   N|   true|
|  2|   N|   true|
|  2|   Y|   true|
|  2|   N|   true|
+---+----+-------+
```

PS: I have also modified your output slightly as having a column named `flagged` with boolean values makes more sense

Comment: Thank you Shubham for the answer. I have a couple of questions if you don't mind as I am fairly new to pyspark. What if I had other values than Y/N and need to check if those 2 exist within the same id? My second question: I've been seeing "F." a lot in the beginning of some functions is it just to replace a dataframe or it has a particular use.

Comment: @Charbel I've edited the answer with case when column may contains other values than `Y/N`. Regarding your second question ,`F` is just an alias given to the module `functions` with is imported from the namespace `pyspark.sql`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a window to collect the set of values and compare to the array of Y and N values:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

a = F.array([F.lit('N'),F.lit('Y')])
out = (df.withColumn("Flagged",F.array_intersect(a,
                      F.collect_set("val1").over(W.partitionBy("id")))==a))
```

---

```
out.show()

+---+----+-------+-------+
| id|val1|   val2|Flagged|
+---+----+-------+-------+
|  1|   Y|Flagged|   true|
|  1|   N|Flagged|   true|
|  2|   N|Flagged|   true|
|  2|   Y|Flagged|   true|
|  2|   N|Flagged|   true|
+---+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. One question though, Is the array comparision in pyspark relies on order of appearance of items to check for equivalence?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes, `array_sort` might be necessary before checking. Thanks for pointing this. However `array_instersect` would return the same order as the left array is I think so here it might not be necessary..!!

Comment: If I want both Y and N to be present does `array_instersect` work? 
I used this but it doesn't seem to work.

`TEST = F.array([F.lit('Y'),F.lit('N')])`
`df.withColumn("TEST_Flagged", TEST.isin(collect_set("val1").over(W.partitionBy("id"))))`

Comment: @Charbel intersection would work, isin wouldnt work, hence your code is not working. Use the same code as my answer..!!